# How do I create a the first mongodb user with authorization enabled?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to create a `admin` user. I've tried several different ways.

I realize that `authorization` is `enabled`, and if I turned it off, then back on it would allow me to create the first user. However I am trying to create the first user while `authorization` is `enabled`.

I have wiped the `data` directory and I am dealing with a fresh database.

> I've been able to use `rs.initiate()` and `db.createUser()` from the console, but what I'm discovering is that it's impossible for me to run a script that both 1)initiates the replica set and 2) creates the admin user using `--eval` at the same time.

My config looks like this:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/mongodb/db/1
net:
  bindIp: localhost,192.168.103.100
  port: 27001
security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /var/mongodb/pki/m103-keyfile
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /var/mongodb/db/mongod1.log
  logAppend: true
processManagement:
  fork: true
replication:
  replSetName: m103-repl
```

Then I connect with this:

```
mongo --host localhost:27001
```

The within the mongo console I tried this:

```
use admin
db.createUser({
  user: "m103-admin",
  pwd: "m103-pass",
  roles: [
    {role: "root", db: "admin"}
  ]
})
```

and I get this error:

```
2020-03-16T19:57:36.796+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't add user: not master :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1437:15
@(shell):1:1
```

Update, I've tried starting the `mongod` then running `rs.initiate`, however I am still getting and issue when I try and create a user.

```sh
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "\nchanging the directory to home dir\n"
cd ~/

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "\nkilling all running mongo processes\n"
sleep 3
kill $(ps aux | grep '[m]ongod' | awk '{print $2}')
sleep 3

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "\nremoving all data directories\n"
rm -rf /var/mongodb/db/1

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "\nremoving all log files\n"
rm -rf /var/mongodb/db/mongod1.log

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "\nremoving all log files\n"
rm -rf /var/mongodb/pki/m103-keyfile

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "\ncreating the keyfile\n"
sudo mkdir -p /var/mongodb/pki
sudo chown vagrant:vagrant -R /var/mongodb
openssl rand -base64 741 > /var/mongodb/pki/m103-keyfile
chmod 600 /var/mongodb/pki/m103-keyfile

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "\ncreating data directories\n"
mkdir -p /var/mongodb/db/1

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "\ntouching the logs\n"
touch /var/mongodb/db/mongod1.log

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "\nstarting up mongo repl 1\n"
mongod --config /shared/replica-sets/mongod-repl-1.conf
sleep 3

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "\nreplicaSet initiate\n"
mongo --port 27001 --eval='rs.initiate()'

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "\ncreating the user\n"
mongo mongodb://localhost:27001/admin?replicaSet=m103-repl --eval='db.createUser({user:"m103-admin",pwd:"m103-pass",roles:[{role:"userAdminAnyDatabase",db:"admin"}]});'
```

Here's what the script returns:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.17
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27001/admin?gssapiServiceName=mongodb&replicaSet=m103-repl
2020-03-16T20:41:39.786+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] Starting new replica set monitor for m103-repl/localhost:27001
2020-03-16T20:41:39.787+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] Successfully connected to localhost:27001 (1 connections now open to localhost:27001 with a 5 second timeout)
2020-03-16T20:41:39.788+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] Successfully connected to 192.168.103.100:27001 (1 connections now open to 192.168.103.100:27001 with a 5 second timeout)
2020-03-16T20:41:39.788+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Unable to reach primary for set m103-repl
2020-03-16T20:41:39.788+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Unable to reach primary for set m103-repl
2020-03-16T20:41:40.333+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Unable to reach primary for set m103-repl
2020-03-16T20:41:40.933+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] changing hosts to m103-repl/192.168.103.100:27001 from m103-repl/localhost:27001
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("bb96245e-3187-4b01-923f-a1a7d7533159") }
MongoDB server version: 3.6.17
2020-03-16T20:41:40.938+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't add user: there are no users authenticated :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1437:15
@(shell eval):1:1
```

Comment: What error do you get from your script?

Comment: @Joe I updated the question with the output from the script.

Comment: `couldn't add user: there are no users authenticated` implies that either there is already a user created or `enableLocalhostAuthBypass` is set to false (or you have some sort of redirection so the server does not see the connection as coming from localhost).  You might try wiping the dbpath and starting over to be sure it's empty.

Comment: I am wiping the data dir and also just set `setParameter` `enableLocalhostAuthBypass` to  `1` and it's still not working :(

Comment: Do you run this scritp on each host? You have to create the keyfile only once and distribute this keyfile to all servers in your Cluster. Follow the tutorials carefully I provided in my answer.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit it's all on one host.

Comment: The keyfile is used for internal communication within the MongoDB Cluster. When you use a single host then the keyfile is useless. Anyway, you have to wait for the Replica Set after `rs.initiate()` till operation is finished.

Answer (score 0):

In a Replica Set you first have to initialize the Replica Set with

```
rs.initiate()
```

Then connect to the PRIMARY host, there you can create the admin user.

Follow the [Deploy Replica Set With Keyfile Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-with-keyfile-access-control/) tutorial, it describes the deployment step-by-step.

For Sharded Cluster follow [Deploy Sharded Cluster with Keyfile Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-sharded-cluster-with-keyfile-access-control/)

Follow these tutorials carefully, have a particular look which commands are executed on each host or only once or just on Primary Hosts, etc.

Comment: This does some the initial issue, but I still haven't been able to create a user.

Comment: Initialize a Replicat Set takes a few seconds, put `while (! db.isMaster().ismaster ) { sleep(1000) }` after `rs.initiate()` to wait till the operation is finished.