# Can't add admin user in Mongo 3.6.8

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I'm trying to add an admin user in Mongo, but I'm having trouble.

I already have `auth = true` commented out inside `/etc/mongodb.conf`.

When I run Mongo, I run these commands in order:

```
mongo

use admin

db.createUser({user:"admin",pwd:"password",roles:["root"]});
```

When I do so, I encounter the following error:

```
2020-10-11T04:50:50.714+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't add user: there are
 no users authenticated :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1437:15
@(shell):1:1
```

I'm not sure exactly how to create an admin user if I have to log in as an admin user to do so. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The default config file is `/etc/mongod.conf` (not `/etc/mongodb.conf`) Verify that you use the correct one at DB startup. Note, there is no `auth` option in the mongoDB config file, see [Configuration File Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/)

Comment: I have mongodb.conf file, not a mongod.conf.

Comment: Is there a keyfile specified in the config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just gave up and started over with a new database, after exporting the old one as a backup.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to disable authentication. With authentication enabled you can still logon to your MonogDB without username/password. However, as soon as you create the first user with `userAdmin` or `userAdminAnyDatabase` role the access control becomes active and you have to authenticate.

This behavior is called [Localhost Exception](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/#localhost-exception)

Is this the **first** user to try to create? Perhaps another admin user already exist. See also [How do I create a the first mongodb user with authorization enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60712530/how-do-i-create-a-the-first-mongodb-user-with-authorization-enabled)

Comment: As far as I know, I don't have any admin users, but I do have a user for one database. If I try to auth using that user, it works inside its own db both not admin, and I get the error I mentioned it I'm authed with that user or not.

Comment: It's possible I have one but forgot... Is there a way to check?

Comment: When you disable authentication (and restart the DB) then you should be able to see all users.

Comment: I'm not sure I am able to disable authentication, because all of the instructions I've seen say to do so inside `/etc/mongod.conf`which I do not have. I only have `mongodb.conf`, and disabling `auth = true` inside that does not seem to have any effect :/

Comment: How do you start the database? Usually with this command you specify the conf-file.

Comment: I have it setup to start on boot. I'm a complete Mongo noob AND a Linux noob, so I don't totally recall how I did it. :/

Comment: Search for a `mongod.service` file on your system. This should tell you which config file is used.

Answer (score -1):

For creating a user you will have to have a user in `admin` database first. So while creating user you need to provide db name and role both. Try creating user with below syntax.

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: "password"
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
  }
)
```

Reference-
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

Comment: That's the whole problem. I can't create the admin user without getting the error described above.

Comment: Have you tried to create user using the command I have provided?

Comment: i think you are not able to create user because you are using `roles:["root"]`.